# Jquery element with dot in tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery when tag string contains dot. When hard coded, query get expected value, but if tag is obtained with a function and concatenated, query fails.

```
var tagWithDot = getTag(...) // tagWithDot === 'tag.withdot'

console.log(tagWithDot === 'tag.withdot') // true

console.log('#' + tagWithDot === '#tag.withdot') // true

console.log('#' + tagWithDot.replace('.', '\\.') === '#tag\\.withdot') // true

console.log($('#' + tagWithDot.replace('.', '\\.')) === $('#tag\\.withdot')) // false

console.log($(('#' + tagWithDot.replace('.', '\\.'))) === $('#tag\\.withdot')) // false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery element with dot in tag name won't work even if replace '.' with '\\.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162341/jquery-element-with-dot-in-tag-name-wont-work-even-if-replace-with)

Comment: What are `...` in `getTag(...)` ?? Is there any question in your question?

Comment: It's an ES9 super spread :P

Comment: The `===` or `==` will never work since you are using jQuery which creates a new object each time it is invoked. Even `$('a:first') === $('a:first')` will not work. Try adding `.get(0)` in both sides of the comparison.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan getTag(...) is a function that returns a string, i.e. 'tag.withdot'

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli $('#' + tagWithDot.replace('.', '\\.')) actually get no query result instead of an object with same content.

Comment: @ZiyuDong ok, i was checking that the problem is not with the tests you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing manually `.` with `\\.` stuff you could use [jQuery's `escapeSelector`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

```js
var tagWithDot = "#tag.withdot";

console.log( $.escapeSelector(tagWithDot) );
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `replace('.','\\.')` seems to work here.

Be aware though if you use `$.escapeSelector` you don't include the # or the # gets escaped too, and is likely not what you wanted.

```js
var tagWithDot = "#tagwith.dot";

setTimeout(function () {
  $(tagWithDot.replace('.','\\.')).text('Replaced');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div>Wait 2 seconds and replace text in div with id #tagwith.dot<div>
<br>
<div id="tagwith.dot">This should get replaced</div>
```